# maven: replace transitive dependency version

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Here a `mvn dependency:tree` snippet:

```
...
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.1.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.1.9:compile
...
```

As you can see, my project is using version 1.1.9 of `io.micrometer:micrometer-core`.

I'd like to use a most recent version of this library.

This version is due to:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.12.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I'm not able to change this version.

Is there any way to override only `io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.1.19` by another one more recent?

Comment: Use a more recent version of Spring Boot....

Answer (score 1):

The best way to override transitive dependencies is to put the version into `<dependencyManagement>`.

Just add an entry like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```

to the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your POM. This will override the transitive dependencies but not influence the direct ones. Furthermore, it will just be ignored if this jar might not be a transitive dependency in the future any more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add the dependency directly to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>  <!-- add latest version here -->
</dependency>
```

Maven will resolve that version because it follows the "nearest definition" (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Note, however, that you should make sure your version is compatible with the Spring Boot project, in case there are compatibility changes. If upgrading Spring Boot is an option, this should be the best way to go, as it should pull a more recent version of micrometer (e.g. `spring-boot-starter-actuator` version 2.4.4 uses micrometer 1.6.5: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.4.4/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.4.4.pom).

Comment: How could I me sure my library is compatible with Spring Boot project?

Comment: @Jordi Ultimately you'd have to test your application. I don't know of a way to tell for sure.